# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32.exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
package com.selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MySelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com");
    }
}
```

Path is correct, but it is returning this issue,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32.exe
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Everything seems to be correct - double check the path.

Comment: Can you run this executable manually? Try to execute it from command line and check if any error is reported.

Comment: yes i m running this manually , could u share this cmd line program to run it ?

Comment: @SupriyaDas After reading the whole discussion. First: please share the screenshot of your folder structure and Second: Try changing the path as "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" and share the result of success or failure. Don't let the discussion open-ended.

Answer (score 2):

Download latest chrome driver from this link : [Download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Extract the zip and Copy choromedriver.exe in E or C

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: i downloaded current version 78.0.3904.70  according to my chrome version (78.0.3904.97) and kept that chrome driver file in C . After that only it showing this error .

Comment: There is a problem with the path. Other than that your code is perfect.

Your folder name is chromedriver_win32 than you path should be 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: this path is 100% correct . i  copied this path n i pasted it .

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of your folder structure where your chromedriver is located? It would help to resolve your problem.

Comment: Attachment icon is  not present , so how  can i upload it ?

Comment: Edit your question. In the body section, there is one icon from where we can upload image in our question.

Comment: Thank you, guys. You helped me too much!

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code and it's working good excepting changing

`"C:\\\Selenium\\\chromedriver_win32.exe"` to `"C:\\\Selenium\\\chromedriver.exe"`.

"`chromedriver_win32`" is zip.

It will be "`chromedriver.exe`" after extracted zip.

Comment: . but  chromedriver_win32 is my folder name . i already extracted  it  from the  zip file . This single forward slash  path is not working .

Comment: For your path "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32.exe" --> It does NOT file name "chromedriver_win32.exe". It only has folder "chromedriver_win32" where contains driver file "chromedriver.exe" and you need to point to this file .exe

Comment: chromedriver_win32 is my folder name n i need to give point  for exe file  . show i wrote at last chromedrive _win32.exe .

Comment: Did you rename exe file to "chromedriver_32.exe"? As I know after extracted zip file, its name of  file .exe is "chromedriver.exe"

Comment: I attached one Path screenshot just go through this . Did you read my comments ? I told you many times chromedriver_win32 is my location folder name where chromedriver.exe file is present .

Answer (score 0):

Seems duplicate but still, you can refer the below links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309669/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalstateexception

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688368/java-selenium-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-illegalstateexception

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite conditions for a successful run.

1. Make sure you have downloaded the correct ChromeDriver according to your Chrome version
   link- [enter link description here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/)https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/
2. `ChromeDriver` should be in the C drive, also extracted.
3. Code should be as follows-

   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.google.com");

Path should be correct with proper spellings, convert all the single slashes into double and add `chromedriver.exe` at the end of path.

4. Another solution without S`ystem.setProperty` is simply adding a folder with `chromedriver.exe` to PATH (if someone doesn't know how - google "set path variable").
   To check that this approach works you may put `chromedriver.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32` folder.